# JSP include prefixes the project name in the link

Tags: html, jsp, tags

I have a html file in a share folder (ie, out of web server location) and I have to include it in a jsp using 
`<jsp:include page="//TestFolder/Sample.html">`. 
While running the application the following error appears on the page:

```
The requested resource (/projectName//TestFolder/Sample.html) is not available
```

Here the application name (/projectName) is being prefixed with the target path. How to get rid of the application name so that the html can be included within the jsp?

Any clarifications would be appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: paste the code of including the html in the jsp page...

Comment: Sorry, I missed it while editing. Now it's been added.

Comment: Have you tried `<jsp:include page="/TestFolder/Sample.html">` - with a `/` before the path instead of a `//` ?

Comment: try removing the "/" from the include path

Comment: Is the HTML in the same web application and if so, why is the prepended application name a problem?

Comment: @Srinivas, I have tried by removing a '/' before the path. Still I am getting the error message saying: The requested resource (/projectName/TestFolder/Sample.html) is not available.

Comment: @Michal M as I mentioned in the question, the html file is in a shared folder (which is outside the server location where the application runs).

Comment: As per my view you have to give the entire path of your html file , because it resides outside the server environment...

Answer (score 1):

The `jsp:include` action can be used only within the same servlet context. It accepts only relative url(either page-relative or application-relative)

Comment: Thanks for your response Sree. I have to find an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, what you are trying to achieve is not possible with jsp inclued tag nor jsp include directive. This is because, at the end of the day, all JSPs become servlets. And a servlet with dependency outside of it's WAR (or any other packaging) would be quite tricky, now, wouldn't it?

I imagine, however, that you could create your own tag that would dynamically read a static HTML file and include it's contents in response. Just put into account that bypassing this limitation will put your application at risk of this HTML not being available unless you prepare your tag for that.

Comment: Thanks Michal M. May be as an alternative, I have to try 'c:import file="filetoBeIncluded"' which is a JSTL tag.

Comment: Well, I was about to write that this won't be possible unless the target file is available as a web resource itself, but, turns out, I would be wrong - guy here did just that with c:import: http://www.coderanch.com/t/287204/JSP/java/JSTL-import so no actual need to write own tags; my bad!